# How does std::optional construct std::variant in place from initializer list?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <optional>
#include <variant>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::optional<std::variant<std::pair<int, int>, std::set<int>>> foo(std::in_place, {1, 4});
}
```

1. This compiles. But how is that possible when `std::variant` [does not have a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list<T>` as its first argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant), but all that this constructor overload of `std::optional` does is [pass the initializer list and forward other arguments to the internal type constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional)?
2. Which type does the `std::variant` hold now, `std::set` or `std::pair`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit complicated, so bear with me.

`optional<T>` has a constructor that takes an `in_place_t` and an `initializer_list<U>` (and optional extra arguments). It will then attempt to construct `T` as if by this statement:

```
T t(list, ...);
```

Where `list` is the initailizer list and `...` are any extra arguments.

`T` is of course a `variant<pair, set>`. `variant` is implicitly convertible from any type `V` through a template constructor. However, this constructor only exists if `V` is a type such that, given a value `v` of this type, the following is true:

```
W w(std::forward<V>(v));
```

Where `W` (I'm running out of letters here) is one of the types in the `variant`. Now `variant` can have multiple types, so `variant` basically considers all possible `W`s and their constructor overloads. So long as overload resolution selects exactly one such constructor among all possible `W`s in the `variant`, the conversion will work.

`pair` has no constructor that takes an `initializer_list`, so none of its constructors count. `set<X>` has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list<X>`.

So, back to the original statement. Because `optional` had an `initializer_list<Y>` parameter where `Y` is deduced, the braced-init-list will deduce `Y` as `int`. And `int` is the same type as the `set` in the `variant`. So `set<int>` can be constructed from an `initailizer_list<int>`.

And therefore, that's what gets created in the `variant`.

If you had a `vector<int>` as part of the `variant`, you'd get a compile error due to the ambiguity of which to call.

And there's not really a way to fix that through `in_place` gymnastics. You can't do `(std::in_place, std::in_place_type<std::set>, {1, 4})`, because the braced-init-list won't get properly deduced. So you'd have to do `(std::in_place, std::set{1, 4})` and let move construction move from the temporary into the `variant`.

Comment: Nice explanation.  So much for readable code...  For us mere mortals, anyway.

Comment: @PaulSanders: It's really just a confluence of various decisions that make sense individually but together interact unexpectedly. `in_place` construction for `optional<T>` should allow access to any constructor for `T`, including initializer_list constructors. `variant<Ts>` should be constructible from any of those `Ts`, or convertible from any type that is convertible to one of those `Ts`. Types with `initializer_list` constructors are convertible from `initializer_list`s. Put them together, and this is what you get.